# Propositional Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Hi guys first time poster here and I am really looking for help in regards to logic. I am trying to learn this by myself using Vellemens books but it doesnt provide much explanation.

Here is the following problem.

(p ^ q) v (p ^ !q).

The problem asks to find simpler formulas equivalent to this.

My problem is this. I know that I have to use the distributive property. So I got the following answer after following the distributive property.

(p v p) ^ (p v !q) ^ (q v p) ^ (q v !q)

Apparently this is already wrong which I dont understand what I did wrong at  this point.

This is what another person got using the distributive property

= ((P∧Q)∨P)∧((P∧Q)∨¬Q))

Comment: How about just $p$?

Comment: P is the answer. However I am more interested in how they got to this answer.

Comment: In your fourfold conjunction, the first member is just $p$, the two middle members together yield just $p$, and the last member is just "true". So, all combined, you get just $p$, as @Ahmed suggests.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&(p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge \lnot q) \\
\quad&\leftrightarrow \quad
\left((p \wedge q) \vee p\right) \wedge \left((p \wedge q) \vee \lnot q\right) 
\qquad\text{(Distribution of disjunction over conjunction)}\\
\quad&\leftrightarrow \quad
p \wedge \left((p \wedge q) \vee \lnot q\right) \qquad\qquad\qquad \text{(By the absorption rule on $(p \wedge q) \vee p$).}\\
\quad&\leftrightarrow \quad
p \wedge \left( (p \vee \lnot q) \wedge (q \vee \lnot q)\right) 
\qquad\quad\;\text{(Distribution of disjunction over conjunction)}\\
\quad&\leftrightarrow \quad
p \wedge \left( (p \vee \lnot q) \wedge T\right) \\
\quad&\leftrightarrow \quad
p \wedge \left( p \vee \lnot q\right) \\
\quad&\leftrightarrow \quad
p \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\text{(By the absorption rule)} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Maybe I am just not smart enough for this. But the distributive law states to foil across right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could your rephrase the question?

Comment: P ∧ (Q ∨ R) is equivalent to (P ∧ Q) ∨ (P ∧ R).   .

Comment: P ∨ (Q ∧ R) is equivalent to (P ∨ Q) ∧ (P ∨ R).

Comment: Both statements that you wrote are correct. The first is the distribution of conjunction over disjunction, and the second  the distribution of disjunction over conjunction (that I have used above).

Comment: So are you saying that both my answer and my friends answer are correct?

Comment: Your friend's application of the distributive law is correct. In fact it is exactly what I did in the first step.
Yours is also correct. But yours is a *double* distributive property (It is like you applied twice in one step). See "double distribution" [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property#Rule_of_replacement).

Answer (score 0):

$(p \land q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) \iff p$

To understand this intuitively, think about it like this:

The statement says that it is either that: $p$ happens and $q$ happens, or $p$ happens and $q$ does not happen. We know that it is always the case that either $q$ happens or does not happen, so the presence of $q$ is no longer necessary.

To see how this would be proved in formal terms, we use the distributive property of $\land$ over $\lor$:

$(p \land q) \lor (p \land \lnot q) \iff p \land (q \lor \lnot q) \iff p$ because $(q \lor \lnot q)$ is a tautology (law of excluded middle).

Comment: Much better Ahmed. Thank you so much. So when there is a tautology that means to just throw it away? Notice the edit that I did. I added an answer that my friend came up with so is he right or am I right when using the distribute property?

Comment: You're welcome. In the "and" statements, yes we can just throw the truths away. Just like how we can throw away the false statements in an "or" situation.

Comment: Ok one last question because this is really bugging me. Did I distribute correctly? Or did my friend distribute correctly?

Comment: Both are correct, but unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: @user249240, your result is just two distributions away from your friend's; namely, distribute each expression in the big brackets in your friend's result and you'll get yours.

Comment: One last question ahmed. The absorption law  states: P ∨ (P ∧ Q) is equivalent to P.

Comment: Does it matter if q is !q or q?? Im thinking it doesnt. Im thinking that as long as the P's match then i should be fine.

Comment: @user249240 It does not; it can be any literal. You can think of $\lnot q$ as another variable $z$ taking the value $\lnot q$.

Comment: So awesome. i am glad I found this site. Thanks lots guys.

Comment: Also I dont want to get downvoted a lot so my question is: Is there a limit to how many questions I ask in the future?

Comment: @user249240 There is no limit in how many questions you can ask on this website. But you have to follow some rules on [how to properly ask a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to increase chances you get an answer. Also avoid extended discussion in the comments section, especially if it is not related to the answer on which you comment!

Answer (score 0):

One way to see that the answer is just $p$ is to realize that the original expression is the result of distributing
$$p\land (q \lor \lnot q)$$
which is certainly just $$p\land T$$ i.e., $$p$$

Comment: I think I understand I just didnt follow everything through

Answer (score 0):

you can use $$f(x) = (f(0) \vee x)\wedge(f(1) \vee x') \tag 1$$

consider your expression $$f(p) = (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge q')\to f(0) =0,\, f(1)= q\vee q' = 1$$  therefore by $(1),$ we have $$ (p \wedge q) \vee (p \wedge q')=(0\vee p )\wedge (1 \vee p') = p\wedge1= p.$$